# Perl getting json values

Tags: json, perl

Got some problems to access json values (translated from xml).

```
for my $PORT (0..$#PORTS)
{
    print Dumper $PORTS[$PORT]->{'neighbor'};
    if (defined($PORTS[$PORT]->{'neighbor'}->{'wwn'}->{'$t'}))
    {
        print Dumper @{$PORTS[$PORT]->{'neighbor'}->{'wwn'}->{$t}};
    }
    else
    {
        print Dumper "not defined"
    }
}
```

Test works when `$PORTS[$PORT]->{'neighbor'}` is empty but I've an error when it contains some value.

```
$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = 'not defined';
$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = 'not defined';
$VAR1 = {
          'wwn' => [
                     {
                       '$t' => 'xxx'
                     },
                     {
                       '$t' => 'yyy'
                     },
                     {
                       '$t' => 'zzz'
                     }
                   ]
        };
Not a HASH reference at ./xxxxx.pl line 209.
```

Line 209 is the line of the test :

```
if (defined($PORTS[$PORT]->{'neighbor'}->{'wwn'}->{'$t'}))
```

Don't know what I miss !
Some clues ?

Comment: You have `->{'$t'}` one place and `->{$t}` another.  The value for the wwn key is an array reference, not a hash reference.

Comment: Corrected in the print line wih no effects...

Comment: The value for the wwn key is an array reference, not a hash reference. You need to do something like `->{'wwn'}->[0]->{'$t'}` or loop over the array or something

Comment: Great ! It works when wwn has multiples values in an array, but not when it had only one value just enclosed in curly brackets (not in array).

Comment: Note you can use `Data::Printer` for nicer printing of refs

Answer (score 0):

Two errors.

In the undefined case, you check if `$PORTS[$PORT]{neighbor}{wwn}{'$t'}` is defined as if `$PORTS[$PORT]{neighbor}{wwn}` is a reference to a hash, but it's `$PORTS[$PORT]{neighbor}{wwn}` that's not defined.

In the defined case, you use `$PORTS[$PORT]{neighbor}{wwn}` as a reference to a hash when it's actually a reference to an array.

```perl
for my $port ( @PORTS ) {
   my $neighbor = $port->{ neighbor };
   if ( my $wwn = $neighbor->{ wwn } ) {
      for ( @$wwn ) {
         my $val = $_->{'$t'};
         ...
      }
   } else {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by checking type returned :

```
for my $port ( @PORTS )
{
    my $neighbor = $port->{ neighbor };
    if ( my $wwn = $neighbor->{ wwn } )
    {
        if (ref($wwn) eq "ARRAY")
        {
            for ( @$wwn )
            {
                my $val = $_->{'$t'};
                print Dumper "array-val : ".$val; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print Dumper "hash-val : ".$wwn->{'$t'};
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print Dumper "pas de wwn pour ce port";
    }
}
```

Thanks to all...